# GCP Vertex AI "Enable necessary APIs" when already enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am new to GCP's Vertex AI and suspect I am running into an error from my lack of experience, but Googling the answer has brought me no fruitful information.

I created a Jupyter Notebook in AI Platform but wanted to schedule it to run at a set period of time. So I was hoping to use Vertex AI's Execute function. At first when I tried accessing Vertex I was unable to do so because the API had not been enabled in GCP. My IT team then enabled the Vertex AI API and I can now utilize Vertex. Here is a picture showing it is enabled. [Enabled API Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUSRO.png)

I uploaded my notebook to a JupyterLab instance in Vertex, and when I click on the Execute button, I get an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnUDv.png) saying I need to "Enable necessary APIs", specifically for Vertex AI API. I'm not sure why this is considering it's already been enabled. I try to click Enable, but it just spins and spins, and then I can only get out of it by closing or reloading the tab.

One other thing I want to call out in case it's a settings issue is that currently my [Managed Notebooks tab says "PREVIEW"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UxKb.png) in the Workbench. I started thinking maybe this was an indicator that there was a separate feature that needed to be enabled to use Managed Notebooks (which is where I can access the Execute button from). When I click on the User-Managed Notebooks and open JupyterLab from there, I don't have the Execute button.

The GCP account I'm using does have billing enabled.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to getting the Execute button to work?

Comment: Hi OP, can you provide the documentation you followed when you create your vertex ai notebook? This will also help us to identify what type of notebook instance you created (user managed or managed). Also, what type of notebook (.ipynb) did you upload in jupyter? Can you also provide screenshot of the "Execute" button you are pertaining to (it might be the Run button, actual Execute button or other button)? This is to properly replicate your use case.

Comment: Hi Scott B, I originally created a User-Managed Notebook through GCP AI Platform. I then saved that notebook (.ipynb file) and uploaded it to the [Managed Notebooks section of the Vertex AI Workbench](https://imgur.com/Arx0w8y). I am not sure which type of notebook it was, as I thought all ipynb notebooks were the same. And yes, here is the [Execute Button](https://imgur.com/NyOBELo) I was referring to. This is the [Quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/schedule-managed-notebooks-run-quickstart) I was referencing.

Comment: Hi OP, I tried to replicate your use case based on your given scenario and was able to set a scheduled run from the "Execute" button. Can you try creating a new notebook instance. Once created, using that new notebook instance, create a new notebook (.ipynb) file using a basic code first like the one shown here https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/schedule-managed-notebooks-run-quickstart#create_a_instance_and_example_notebook_file. And then try to click Execute button and see if you can already create a scheduled run.

Comment: I followed the instructions in that guide to a T just now, creating a new instance, a new notebook with only the datetime code, and I get the same error message about needing to enable the Vertex AI API. I'm wondering if, even though the API shows as enabled, if maybe there was a certain feature when enabling that needed to be selected? Or maybe the correct permissions weren't granted to my user? I am going to reconnect with my IT department again to see what they say.

Comment: In the meantime, can you confirm if your button says "Execute" or "Executor"? In the Quickstart guide it says to click the "Executor" button, but mine says "Execute". I assumed it was just an update to the UI, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: Turns out the API was enabled, and permissions were granted to the service account, but because I was a single-user for the Managed Notebook instance, IT needed to add that permission to my individual account. Thanks for your help in attempting to troublshoot.

Comment: Hi @JamesS, based on your last comment, I assume that you already found the solution to your question. With this, can you post it as an answer and accept it? This is for the benefit of the community that may encounter the same use case in the future.

Comment: In addition, can you share what exact role did your IT add to your individual account and if it is through IAM page of GCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @JamesS comments, the issue was solved by adding necessary permissions on his individual account since it is the account configured on OP's `Managed Notebook Instance` in which has an access mode of `Single user only`.

Based on my testing when I tried to replicate the scenario, "Enable necessary APIs" message box will continue to show when the user has no *"Vertex AI User"* role assigned to it. And in conclusion of my testing, below are the minimum **roles** required when trying to create a *Scheduled run* on a `Managed Notebook Instance`.

- **Notebook Admin** - For access of the notebook instance and open it through Jupyter. User will be able to run written codes in the Notebook as well.
- **Vertex AI User** - So that the user can **create schedule run** on the notebook instance since the creation of the scheduled run is under the Vertex AI API itself.
- **Storage Admin** - Creation of scheduled run will require a Google Cloud Storage bucket location where the job will be saved

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: Thanks Scott B! Based on what IT told me, it was the Vertex AI User option that I was missing. I most likely already had the other permissions since he didn't say anything about that. Thanks for putting this together as I didn't have that complete information.